# How to split email addresses with ; in a qw

Tags: perl

```
my @TeamRecipients = qw(
   mike@domain.com
   john@domain.com
   ken@domain.com
   rajah@domain.com
);



sub sendEmailToTeam
{
   my ($title, $msg) = @_;

   my $email = new Common::Email(
    'Sender' => 'rajah@domain.com',
    'To' => \@TeamRecipients,
    'Subject' => $title,
    'Message' => $msg
   );    

   if (not $ENV{'NIGHTLY_RUN_DEBUG_MODE'})
   {
      $email->send();
   }
}
```

In the code above, the domain is my company name and individual team members are receiving emails without any issue but they can't reply in the same thread because the email address are in combined as shown: "mike@domain.com john@domain.com ken@domain.com rajah@domain.com" , instead of "mike@domain.com; john@domain.com; ken@domain.com; rajah@domain.com"

I modified TeamRecipients to

```
my @TeamRecipients = qw(
   mike@domain.com;
   john@domain.com;
   ken@domain.com;
   rajah@domain.com;
);
```

but it didn't work. Team members didn't get the initial email either.

I also introduce a intermediate array like bellow

```
my @MyTeamRecipients = map { split(/;/, $_)} @TeamRecipients;
```

but it didn't work either.

Experts,

Is there any solutions?

Thanks,
Rajah

Comment: BTW, `split` is for creating arrays from text strings; you already have an array, but you need to join it using a text string.

Comment: For what it's worth, the standard character for separating e-mail addresses in mail headers is a comma, not a semi-colon. (I believe the Outlook UI shows it as a semi-colon, but it still correctly uses comma over the wire.)

Comment: Sounds like your Common::Email is buggy.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html):

```
    'To' => join(';', @TeamRecipients),
```

Comment: If `Common::Email` (not on CPAN, homebuilt?) expects an array ref, you would have to do `'To' => [ join ... ]`

Comment: Thank you for your hints. But unfortunately non of them resolve my issue.

Comment: *"none of them resolve my issue"* is not enough information to diagnose the problem.  You've included no information about your module `Common::Email`, so there is nothing else that we can add.